# On Ubuntu 20.04 how do you open a port in the firewall

Tags: networking, 20.04, firewall

Googled and found nothing recent. I did find docs on ufw and I ran:

```
thomas@Westeros:~/git/heavyweight-software$ sudo ufw status verbose
[sudo] password for thomas: 
Status: inactive
```

So I'm thinking it isn't running ufw anymore. I can ping my computer, but I can't connect to it on my development web server port 4200. Can't find any docs on ubuntu site either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally found the answer here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-configure-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/

The answer appears to be that ufw is disabled by default and there is a default policy in place that doesn't use that. So I ran:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

And then ran

```
sudo ufw allow 4200
```

now `sudo ufw status verbose` returns me the information I wanted to see.

Additionally, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492354/how-to-allow-access-outside-localhost taught me to run `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` to serve my angular app outside of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo ufw allow 4200`

This will open port 4200

Comment: Let me try again. When I run ufw status verbose it says status: inactive, which tells me that ufw is not my firewall. Running the allow 4200 command accomplished nothing and the status still says inactive.

Comment: Ah I see. Are you connecting through LAN or the internet, as you will need to portforward if you are connecting over the internet.

Comment: I am connecting over a LAN.

Comment: UFW is the default firewall application. You could try enabling it and adding a rule, but other than that I am not sure.